# how to serialize a null string to an empty element using XmlSerializer?

Tags: .net, xmlserializer

I have an asp.net application which is consuming a java web-service. The java web-service is expecting an empty element to be passed when the string is `Null/empty`. However I'm finding it difficult to achieve this through XmlSerializer.

I tried `IsNullable=true;` but this is adding additional attributes and my java service is not processing these attributes. Any suggestions to achieve this will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A null value usually results in a missing element, or an element with xsi:nil="true" attribute. What attribute are you getting which your service cant handle? More @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybce7f69.aspx

Comment: I'm getting xsi:nil="true" attribute as expected but the java code is not processing the request if it contains this attribute

Comment: I believe that the correct thing to do would be to modify the java service into accepting xsi:nil, but I guess it's a remote service that you cant change. My only solution to this would be to change the property of the serialized object to return an empty string instead of a null value. Is this feasable?